# Alphabetical Sorting Not Printing Correctly In Java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I correctly alphabetically sort user inputted string. Is my logic correct on the code below? The output is not correct, and the last printed name is always wrong.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortNames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a list of names delimited by commas: ");
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = userInputScanner.nextLine();
        String userInputArray[]=null;
        userInputArray= userInput.split(",");
        
        String ListOrdered[]=DisplayListOrdered(userInputArray);
        //System.out.print(Arrays.toString(ListOrdered));
         for (String name : ListOrdered) {
                System.out.println(name);
            }

    }
    public static String[] DisplayListOrdered(String userInputArray1[])
    {   
    
        Arrays.sort(userInputArray1,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        return userInputArray1;
        
    }

}
```

How can I correctly alphabetically sort user inputted string. Is my logic correct on the code below? The output is not correct, and the last printed name is always wrong. Would using an array list be more optimal?

Comment: Wrong in what way?

Comment: Okay so after further review, the issues lies in how I am splitting the string into an array before sorting. Depending on how i use the split method ( userInput.split(",") or userInput.split("[, ]"); affects wether it prints alphabetically or not, but now the issue is when I use the split with commas and spaces I cant have the user input full names because it splits by space. But it doesn't sort correctly without it and only works if the user inputs perfectly using a comma after each name and no extra spaces

Comment: `userInput.split(",\\s*");` - a comma followed by any number of spaces, even zero.

Comment: If I split using the space, then I run into the issue of not being able to input first and last names together, but i cant sort it correctly without splitting by spaces

Comment: I recommend splitting an what *isn't* a word: `userInput.split("\\W+")` ie split on **one or more non-word chars**

Comment: Using userInput.split("\\W+") doesn't allow me to enter first and last names as it separates the full name. what can I do to get the full name, but not run into issues if the user adds extra spaces before the comma to separate each name they input. that messes with the alphabetical order for some reason

Comment: `userInputArray = userInput.split("\\s*,\\s*");`

Comment: @MustafaErdogan I'm pretty sure you made a comment about my previous comment, did you not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Just split & strip strings

Using regex, as suggested in the Comments, may be overkill for your goal.

- [Split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) on COMMA (`,`).
- [Strip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) away any extra whitespace characters.

```java
String input = "dog,cat , bird ,     fish";
String[] parts = input.split( "," );
for ( int index = 0 ; index < parts.length ; index++ )
{
    parts[ index ] = parts[ index ].strip( );
}
Arrays.sort( parts );
```

> Would using an array list be more optimal?

Using the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) is generally much more convenient than arrays.

```java
String input = "dog,cat , bird ,     fish";
List < String > parts  = new ArrayList <>( List.of( input.split( "," ) ) );
List < String > strings = new ArrayList <>( parts.size() );
for ( String part : parts )
{
    strings.add( part.strip() );
}
strings.sort( String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER );  // Beware: This comparator does *not* take locale into account. Use `Collator` instead.
```

Dump to console.

```java
strings.forEach( System.out :: println );
System.out.println( "strings = " + strings );
```

In modern Java, we can simplify that to a one-liner by using stream, lambda, and method reference.

Also, Java 21+ has a more general interface now to indicate a sorted collection: [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html). See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

```java
SequencedCollection < String > sortedStrings =
        Arrays
                .stream( 
                    "dog,cat , bird ,     fish"
                    .split( "," ) 
                )
                .map( String :: strip )
                .sorted( )
                .toList( );
```

---

Reminder: Variable names in Java by convention start with a lowercase letter. So `listOrdered`, not `ListOrdered`.

Ditto for method names: `displayListOrdered`, not `DisplayListOrdered`.

Comment: You can get the trimmed parts in one short line: `String[] strings = input.replaceAll("^\\W+", "").split("\\W+");`. Or the whole thing: `var sorted = Arrays.stream(input.replaceAll("^\\W+", "").split("\\W+")).sorted( ).toList( );`

Answer (score -1):

Well... I think you should give a input sample.

Maybe there is white space or something.

Add this after spliting.

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInputArray.length; i++) {
    // trim to remove leading and trailing 
    userInputArray[i] = userInputArray[i].trim();  
}
```